# Can somebody explain how javascript Arithmetic expressions work?

Tags: javascript, arithmetic-expressions

Let's evaluate this code for swapping two variables :

```
var a = 5, b = 3; 
a = ( a -( b = ( a = a+b ) - b ) );
```

I was expecting that new value of `a` should be `3` and value of `b` should be `5`.  But I got  values as `a = 0 and b = 5`;

I went and read the EcmaScript Arithmetic expression and found that this will be evaluated from left-to-right. ( but not completely clear ).

So I tried this one

```
var a = 5, b = 3; 
a = ( ( b = ( a = a+b ) - b ) - a );
```

Now I got `a = -3 and b = 5`.  Can somebody explain me why this is happening like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, the expression is evaluated from left to right, meaning the first time a is encountered, its value is still 5. This comes down to:

```
var a = 5, b = 3; 
a = ( a -( b = ( a = a+b ) - b ) );
a = 5 - (b = (a=(5+3)) - b);
a = 5 - (b = 8 - b);
a = 5 - 5; AND b = 5
```

In the second one, the a value is evaluated after the assignment because it is on the right

```
var a = 5, b = 3;
a = ( ( b = ( a = a+b ) - b ) - a );
a = ( ( b = 8 - b ) - a ); AND a = 8
a = ( 5 - 8 ); AND a = 8; AND b = 5;
a = - 3;
```

It all comes down to the order of the evaluation of the operands.

Typically in the first case, a is evaluated to 5, then `b = ( a = a+b ) - b` is evaluated, and only during this evaluation the value of a changes, but is not backported.

In the second example, `( b = ( a = a+b ) - b )` is evaluated first, changing the a value to 8, then a is evaluated, and is found to be 8

## A more trivial example is :

```
var a = 5
a = a + (a = 2)
// a = 7
```

`a` is evaluated to 5, then `(a = 2)` is evaluated to 2 and a is set to 2, then `5+2` is evaluated and a is set to 7.

On the other hand :

```
var a = 5
a = (a = 2) + a
// a = 4
```

`(a = 2)` is evaluated to 2 and a is set to 2, then `a` is evaluated to 2, then `2+2` is evaluated and a is set to 4

Answer (score 2):

Here is the explanation, I hope it is clear because it is not so obvious.
JS and all other languages create a tree to evaluate expressions. The tree assigns a weight to each operator depending on their position and on the braces.

First, here is the steps JS would process the expression:

```
Step 0. a = ( a - ( b = ( a = a+b ) - b ) );   a=5, b=3
Step 1.                   a = a+b              a=8, b=3
Step 2.             b = a - b                  a=8, b=5 
Step 3. a = a - b                              a=0, b=5
```

At each step it processes one operator.

And this is the tree it creates from you expression:

```
    =
  /   \
 a     - 
     /    \
   a       =
          /  \   
         b    -            
             / \
            =   b
           /  \
          a    +
              / \
             a   b
```

The tree is then processed from bottom to top.

Comment: But , in the third step `a = a-b` should give me result as `a=3 and b=5`. isn't it ? Because step2 changed the value of `a and b` as `a = 8  and b =3`. I'm bit confused

Comment: Look at my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19045816/1324929. What @KLiFF fails to mention is that with assignment, the first step is expression evaluation on the right side. Thus, a = ( a -( b = ( a = a+b ) - b ) ) becomes a = ( 5 -( b = ( a = 5+3 ) - 3 ) ). After that, the right side, from inner parens to outer parens, a = 5+3, a becomes 8, b = 8-3, b becomes 5 and finally a = 5-5, a becomes 0, b remains 5.

Comment: not exactly. The tree is processed from left to right, otherwise a = 8 in your first left node.

Comment: It is indeed very confusing, but here is the explanation:
The a from the left was already evaluated and has a value of 5, the a from the right is is the result of the calculations from the right branch of the tree and has a value of 8. So there is in fact an a and an a'.

Comment: How the tree is processed exactly ? Is it from bottom to top OR left to right ? I read that arithmetic expressions are evaluated from left to right. If I apply the same logic here, then it makes sense .. It produces the correct ouput .. Only one more clarification I need is when processing the left node, it should be processing all of it's child nodes before moving to the right node .. isn't it ?

Comment: That's correct, in this example the 'b' at the right of `( a = a+b ) - b` is evaluated after the 'b' at the left side. here is a code you can use to see what branch is evaluated in what order using firebug:
`var a = 5, b = 3; 
var say = function(t, v) { console.log(t + "." + v); return v;}
a = say("left", a) -( b = ( a = a + say("left-b", b) ) - say("right-b", b))`

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = 5, b = 3;
a = ( ( b = ( a = a+b ) - b ) - a );
```

It will operate in this way.

```
a = a + b //8
b = a - b //8-3=5
a = b - a //5-8=-3
```

Comment: Why did the 
    a = ( a -( b = ( a = a+b ) - b ) );
gave me `a=0 and b=5`

Comment: Yes, my best guess is a is set to 5 before the expression (a = a+b), so a stays 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ( a -( b = ( a = a+b ) - b ) )
```

is similar to this

```
a = ( 5 -( b = ( a = 5+3 ) - 3 ) ) // a = 8
// a = ( 5 - ( b = 8 - 3 ) ) // b = 5
// a = ( 5 - 5 ) // a = 0
```

meaning it will replace a and b on the left side of = in one go with the same initial values,
it's not similar to this sequence

```
a = a+b; // a = 8
b = a-b; // b = 5
a = a-b; // a = 3
```

as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = 5, b = 3; 
a = ( a -( b = ( a = a+b ) - b ) );
```

1) a = a(5) - (rest of expression, where 2 parts will be calculated soon)

2) b = (a = a+b // and it's still not calculated) - b (which is 3, because new b is not changed yet)

3) a = 5(a) + 3(b) = 8

4) b(we are back to point 2) = 8(new a) - 3(old b) = 5

5) a(point 1) = 5(old a) - 5(new b) = 0

New a = 0, new b = 5

```
var a = 5, b = 3; 
a = ( ( b = ( a = a+b ) - b ) - a );
```

1) b = ( a = a+b ) - 3(b)

2) a = 5(a) + 3(b) = 8

3) b = 8(new a) - 3(old b) = 5

4) a(final) = 5(new b) - 8(new a) = -3

New a = -3, new b = 5

I hope it's readable :D